# How to include security classification in Beamer Gemini template in headline

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I would like to add the security classification (e.g., classified, unclassified, etc.) in the top right of the headline in the Gemini beamerposter theme available here:
https://github.com/anishathalye/gemini

With the two logos (left and right) uncommented in the example file poster.tex, I get the following output:
[image: Initial test]

If I add the following line (identified with **) in beamerthemegemini.sty to insert the classification in the right column on top of the logo:

```
\begin{column}{\maxlogowidth}
        \vskip5ex
        \ifdefined\insertlogoright
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \raggedleft
        **\usebeamerfont{headline author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{headline author}Unclassified\\[1ex]**
        \insertlogoright
        \hspace{10ex}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \else\fi
      \end{column}
```

The hspace no longer seems to work and moreover both the logo and the text get cropped on the right:
[image: Modified template]

I would like to keep the same hspace on the right with both the classification and the logo ragged on the left.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=120,height=72,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{gemini}
\usecolortheme{gemini}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\newlength{\sepwidth}
\newlength{\colwidth}
\setlength{\sepwidth}{0.025\paperwidth}
\setlength{\colwidth}{0.3\paperwidth}

\newcommand{\separatorcolumn}{\begin{column}{\sepwidth}\end{column}}

\title{Some fancy title: followed by some more text}

\author{Alyssa P. Hacker \inst{1} \and Ben Bitdiddle \inst{2} \and Lem E. Tweakit \inst{2}}

\institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} Some Institute \samelineand \inst{2} Another Institute}

\logoright{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{logo1.pdf}}
\logoleft{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{logo2.pdf}}

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

[image: Logo1]
[image: Logo2]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: All the files are available on the provided Github link and the line I added in beamerthemegemini.sty is shown between ** ** (I don't know if it is possible to highlight code). The linked poster.tex example is quite lengthy (and I only uncommented the \logoleft and \logoright lines), are you suggesting I should still paste this code here with all the theme-related code (sty files) that are provided on Github? I thought it would be easier for other users to download the code directly instead of copy/pasting.

Comment: The style files, which you did not modify, can be downloaded from github, but please add a short test file to your question, which we can use without having to make any modifications first.

Comment: I have added a MWE with the 2 logos, which should compile to the first image shown (before the added line in beamerthemegemini.sty)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like a `\parbox` to add both your text and the image as the logo:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=120,height=72,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{gemini}
\usecolortheme{gemini}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\newlength{\sepwidth}
\newlength{\colwidth}
\setlength{\sepwidth}{0.025\paperwidth}
\setlength{\colwidth}{0.3\paperwidth}

\newcommand{\separatorcolumn}{\begin{column}{\sepwidth}\end{column}}

\title{Some fancy title: followed by some more text}

\author{Alyssa P. Hacker \inst{1} \and Ben Bitdiddle \inst{2} \and Lem E. Tweakit \inst{2}}

\institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} Some Institute \samelineand \inst{2} Another Institute}

\logoright{\parbox{13cm}{\raggedleft Unclassified\linebreak \includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-duck}}}
\logoleft{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-duck}}

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

[image]